# Equal Objects not being filtered by Stream.distinct()

Tags: java, java-stream, equality

I have a stream of `Element` objects that I needed to filter based on equality. This seems easy enough with `.distinct()` but I was getting abnormal results. Even though the objects return as equal they are not filtered by `.distinct()`.

What am I missing? Proof below --

```
List<Element> elements = getStream().filter(e -> e.getName().equals("userId")).collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println("Elements with same name: " + elements.size());

if(elements.size() > 1) {
    System.out.println("Equals?: " + elements.get(0).equals(elements.get(1)));
}

System.out.println("Distinct Elements: " + getStream().distinct().count());
System.out.println("Full Elements: " + getStream().count());
```

Outputs:

```
Elements with same name: 2
Equals?: true
Distinct Elements: 8
Full Elements: 8
```

Comment: does your `Element` class override `equals` ?

Comment: Yes. I am using the Apache EqualsBuilder. It does return correctly as shown above.

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (obj == this) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj.getClass() != getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        Element other = (Element) obj;
        return new EqualsBuilder().append(getName(), other.getName()).isEquals();
    }

Comment: also - you will get `IllegalStateException` if you run this code. `collect` method is terminal operation

Comment: That is correct... I obfuscated the stream creation method. But they are all the same so its equivalent. Changed it to getStream().

Comment: Could you post the whole class. There's a lot of guessing what happens before

Comment: @k0ner I really doubt that will clarify things as the code is not simple. I could provide specific portions if needed. I am simply asking if anyone else has experienced streams with objects that evaluate as equal but are not filtered by distinct. There must be more going on then listed in the docs.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

According to the `distinct()` method of the Stream API (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#distinct--):

> Returns a stream consisting of the distinct elements (according to Object.equals(Object)) of this stream.

Do you override `equals()` and `hashCode()` of the `Element` class appropriately?

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode--

Comment: We were not overriding `hashCode()`. That was the problem. Although the docs state that they use `equals()` it is not sufficient for `distinct()`. Interesting... thanks!

Comment: hashCode() and equals(object) both are called while using the distinct(), so it becomes necessary to override these two methods.